# Google Cloud Platform, Storage buckets with Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-storage

I have created a complete application (already with many users) in Android Studio for listing and downloading objects in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket, with the Java API.
I have two Google Cloud Storage Buckets, an original and another for testing: the bucket was replicated because of issues with latency.

The application is being used in the Middle East, and the bucket is in the 'US' as 'multi_regional'.

I am using this in my App gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev79-1.22.0'
```

The application does not work well in Saudi Arabia - often there are no results returned from this code:

```
public List<String> listBucket_withPrefix(String bucketName, String prefix) throws Exception {

    Storage storage = getStorage();

    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Storage.Objects.List listobjects = storage.objects().list(bucketName);
    listobjects.setPrefix(prefix);
    long maxResults = 100000L;
    listobjects.setMaxResults(maxResults);

    final List<StorageObject> items = new ArrayList<StorageObject>();

    Objects objects;

    boolean get_token = true;

    do {
        try
        {
            Log.e("CLOUDSTORAGE","GETTING BUCKET LIST");
            objects = listobjects.execute();
```

This method is called from the main activity of the application in a thread:

```
// get cloud storage bucket file list - then send to app
public void listAllFiles_thread(final String[] params, final downloadLib newLib)
{
    new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

            String bucketName = params[0];
            String fileName = params[1];
            String destinationDirectory = params[2];
            String prefix = params[3];

            CloudStorage myStorage = new CloudStorage();
            myStorage.SetContext(myContext);

            List<String> callbackresult = null;
            try
            {
                callbackresult = myStorage.listBucket_withPrefix(bucketName, prefix);
```

The results are unexpected, often there are no results returned from

```
objects = listobjects.execute();
```

above in the cloud storage list method 'listBucket_withPrefix'

I have attempted to use the other bucket location: in 'Asia' as 'multi-regional'.

The results are very bizarre, testing with a Samsung S7 Android 6, and a Samsung S6.

1) On the Samsung S7 Android 6.0.1 both these buckets are seen and data is downloaded.

2) Using a Samsung S6 Android 6.0.1 the bucket will work in debug mode, and in usual monitoring mode (play in Android Studio). If the release APK is used, there is NOTHING returned from the list method.